# LWC Typescript this parameter type

Tags: lightning-web-components

```js
defineProperties(Element.prototype, {
    querySelector: {
        value: querySelectorPatched,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    },
    querySelectorAll: {
        value(this: HTMLBodyElement): NodeListOf<Element> {
            const nodeList = arrayFromCollection(
                elementQuerySelectorAll.apply(this, ArraySlice.call(arguments) as [string])
            );

            if (!featureFlags.ENABLE_NODE_LIST_PATCH) {
                const filteredResults = getFilteredArrayOfNodes(
                    this,
                    nodeList,
                    ShadowDomSemantic.Disabled
                );
                return createStaticNodeList(filteredResults);
            }

            return createStaticNodeList(
                getFilteredArrayOfNodes(this, nodeList, ShadowDomSemantic.Enabled)
            );
        },
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    },

});
```

I want to understand this part of the following Typescript code here:

```
value(this: HTMLBodyElement): NodeListOf<Element>
```

I believe this code is overriding the standard `querySelectorAll` method, therefore simulating Shadow DOM. But the method is being defined on an `Element`, yet the value for `this` in the function is `HTMLBodyElement`. Does this mean the method can only be called from a `body` element? Or perhaps it's called from `Element` and then casted to `HTMLBodyElement`? Can someone explain the logic of this code? This is a part of the following [LWC source](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/packages/%40lwc/synthetic-shadow/src/faux-shadow/element.ts#L365). I know there are some people here that probably wrote this code so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The author of that code, [Caridy](https://github.com/caridy), should be able to answer more definitively. I can't see any good reason why it should be HTMLBodyElement vs just Element, since HTMLBodyElement is a child class of Element and HTMLElement.

Comment: Do you know if he is a member here?

Comment: They have an [account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/27857/caridy-pati%C3%B1o) here, but haven't logged in for 4+ years.